# Change the code of a javascript function

Tags: javascript

Actually my idea is the following: i have a div tag that displays the result of a function called "afficher_general()" inside a script tag, and a button that calls a first function called "Ajouter_general()" that's supposed to change a string inside the function "afficher_general()"

```
var general = document.getElementById("general");
general.innerHTML = general.innerHTML.replace('//WRITE', ch);
```

the button is as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="ajouter au graphe general" id="id1" onClick="Ajouter_general();afficher_general();" />
```

But this doesn't seem to work because i've been told that a script is loaded only once and it cannot be changed. So is there any solution ? Thanks in advance.

So i'll add what contain the functions. Actually i'm working with Amcharts . the function afficher_generalis as follows:

```
<script name="general" id="general" type="text/javascript">
    function afficher_general()
    {

                    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                    chart.categoryField = "country";
                    chart.startDuration = 1;                
                    // WRITE
                    chart.write("chartContainer");


    }
</script>
```

instead of the comment //WRITE i wish to add the a code everytime the button is pressed. the function is as follows:

```
function Ajouter_general(ind){
var ch="";
var couleur = getSelectValueId("background-color"+ind);
var transparence = getSelectValueId("transparence"+ind);
var type = get_radio_value_type(ind);
var balloon = getSelectValueId("balloon-color"+ind);
if(type == "column")
                {
                ch=ch+"var graph"+ind+" = new AmCharts.AmGraph();";
                                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".valueField = "+"visits"+";"
                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".balloonColor = "+balloon+";";
                                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".type = "+type+";";
                                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".fillAlphas = "+transparence+";";
                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".fillColors = ["+couleur+"];";
                ch=ch+"graph"+ind+".lineColor = ["+couleur+"];";
                ch=ch+"chart.addGraph(graph"+ind+");";
                ch=ch+"// WRITE";
                }
var general = document.getElementById("general");
general.innerHTML = general.innerHTML.replace('//WRITE', ch);
}
```

since Amcharts uses the script to draw graphs inside a chart, i would like to be able to dynamically add those graphs everythime the button is pressed.

Comment: Why do you want to change the **text** of the JS function?  First of all, it won't work because the JS source is parsed once and stored in memory.  But mostly, why can't you just use a variable and update that variable on the click of your button?

Comment: Because the string i want to add is actually a js code that needs to be executed inside a script tag.

Comment: I still would expect there might be a way to make the function more dynamic and not actually have to overwrite it.  Can you post the function (or a simplified version of it) to see if people here might suggest alternatives?

Comment: You need to think of your problem in a way that doesn't require you to change the JavaScript *code* but instead the *data* on which the code operates.  See if you can restate/modify your question as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to change the definition of a function, you could always just redefine it (functions are just objects assigned to variables):

```
var Ajouter_general = function () {
    // redefine the afficher_general function
    afficher_general = function () {
        // change it to whatever you want
    };
};
```

That being said, this is generally a bad practice and the same functionality can be better accomplished by using function parameters.